# Samba Share Permissions Issue - Public share with file-stystem permissions only

Tags: windows, linux, permissions, samba

I'm trying to create a Samba share on a Linux (SLES10) system, but I'm having trouble with the Samba permissions.  I want to create this as a public share, with file permissions controlled at the file-system level (so all users can map the drive, but they can only browse further if they have further file-system permissons).

I've been able to create the share, and map to it with any user.  The problem is that I only seem able to obtain sufficient permissions if I login as "root".  If I login with another user, even if they have permissions to read and write to the underlying folder, I cannot browse that any folders at all.

Here is the share information from /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[sambatest]
        comment = Samba Test
        public = yes
        path = /var/opt/folder
        read only = No
        writeable = Yes
        write list = user1 user2 user3
        browseable = Yes
```

Here is an example of the directory permissions in the shared folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 user1 group1   40 Nov  4 17:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 user1 group1 4096 Oct 20 09:20 ..
drwxrwx---  4 user1 group1   41 Nov  4 17:02 BASE
drwxrwx---  6 user1 group1   78 Oct 28 10:11 Files
drwxrwx---  2 user1 group1   22 Nov  4 17:02 test
```

After the mapping the drive with the credentials of "user1", I try to browse "test" from Windows XP, but get a message "Z:\test is not accessible: Access is denied".

If I map the same shared folder using the "root" credentials, it works.

Little help?  I'm sure I've come across this before, but can't figure out how to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try chmod that dir with 755 and try with this config

```
[sambatest]
    comment = Samba Test
    public = yes
    path = /var/opt/folder
    read only = yes
    writeable = yes
    write list = user1 user2 user3
    browseable = yes
    create mask = 0775
```

More info on:

- http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch06_02.html
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-set-permissions-to-samba-shares.html

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This sort of worked, but basically made the directories completely accessible to the public.  

But, because of this, I think I've realised that the authentication of the user credentials I'm using to map the Samba share is not working.  It only seems to authenticate root, but no other user.  I can't see anything specifically related to this in /var/log/messages (although there are a bunch of messages but I think they just relate to the lack of a CUPS print server):

Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused

Comment: Does that 'create mask' even match the chmod you asked him to make?  Doesn't look like it to me.  To ,  this chmod method is the wrong way to go.   A Samba config would be the real way to fix this if we knew what the real answer was.